# NxN detect win for tic-tac-toe

Tags: pygame

I have tried to generalise my tic-tac-toe game for an NxN grid. I have everything working but am finding it hard to get the code needed to detect a win.
This is my function at the moment where I loop over the rows and columns of the board. I can't figure out why it's not working currently. Thanks

```
def check_win(array_board):
    global winner
    for row in range(N):
        for i in range(N-1):
            if array_board[row][i] != array_board[row][i+1] or array_board[row][i] == 0:
                break
        if i == N-1:
            winner = array_board[row][0]
            pygame.draw.line(board, (0, 0, 0), (75, (row * round(height / N) + 150)), (825, (row * round(height / N) + 150)), 3)

    for col in range(N):
        for j in range(N-1):
            if array_board[j][col] == 0 or array_board[col][j] != array_board[col][i+1]:
                break
        if j == N - 1:
                winner = array_board[0][col]
                pygame.draw.line(board, (0, 0, 0), (col * round(width / N) + 150, 75), (col * round(width / N) + 150, 825), 3)
```

Comment: What is the idea behind using `N-1` on the inner loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify in your question, so *my* noughts-and-crosses grid is a 2D array of characters, with some default "empty" string (a single space).

```
def getEmptyBoard( size, default=' ' ):
    """ Create a 2D array <size> by <size> of empty string """
    grid = []
    for j in range( size ):
        row = []
        for i in range( size ):  # makes a full empty row
            row.append( default )
        grid.append( row )
    return ( size, grid )
```

So given a 2D grid of strings, how does one check for a noughts-and-crosses Win?  This would be when the count of the same character in a particular row or column is *equal to the size of the grid*.

Thus if you have a 5x5 grid, any `row` with 5 of the same item (say 'x') is a winner.  Similarly for a column... 5 lots of 'o' is a win.

So given a 2D array, how do you check for these conditions.  One way to do this is to tally the number of occurrences of separate symbols in each cell.  If that tally reaches the `5` (grid size), then whatever that symbol is, it's a winner.

```
def checkForWin( board, default=' ' ):
    winner = None
    size = board[0]
    grid = board[1]

    ### Tally the row and column
    for j in range( size ):
        col_results = {}

        ### Count the symbols in this column
        for i in range( size ):
            value = grid[i][j]
            if ( value in col_results.keys() ):
                col_results[ value ] += 1
            else:
                col_results[ value ] = 1

        ### Check the tally for a winning count
        for k in col_results.keys():
            if ( k != default and col_results[k] >= size ):
                winner = k     # Found a win
                print("Winner: column %d" % ( j ) )
                break

        if ( winner != None ):
            break

    # TODO: also implement for rows
    # TODO: also implement for diagonals

    return winner  # returns None, or 'o', 'x' (or whatever used for symbols)
```

The above function uses two loops and a python dictionary to keep a list of what's been found.  It's possible to check both the row and columns in the same loops, so it's not really row-by-row or column-by-column, just two loops of `size`.

Anyway, so during the loop when we first encounter an `x`, it will be added to the dictionary, with a value of `1`.  The next time we find an `x`, the dictionary is used to tally that occurrence, `dict['x'] → 2`, and so forth for the entire column.

At the end of the loop, we iterate through the dictionary keys (which might be  , `o`, and `x`) checking the counts.  When the count is the same size as a row or column, it's a winning line.

Obviously if there's no win found, we zero the tally and move to the next column/row with the outer-loop.